# Selecting most recent update for each inquiry

Tags: sql

I have two tables and need to create a query that brings back all the currently open inquiries with the latest diary update

Table - sv_inquiry

```
inquiry_id | status  | state       | owner_grp |
------------------------------------------------
1            OPEN     Acknowledged    DEV
2            OPEN     Acknowledged    DEV
3            OPEN     Reassigned      DEV
4            OPEN     Reassigned      DEV
```

Table - sv_diary

```
diary_id| inquiry_id | change_dt| change_uid |
------------------------------------------------
1          1           2/1/2013    JBLOGGS
2          1           3/1/2013    JBLOGGS
3          1           4/1/2013    JSMITH
1          2           2/1/2013    JBLOGGS
2          2           4/1/2013    JSMITH
1          3           4/1/2013    JSMITH
2          3           6/1/2013    JBLOGGS
1          4           5/1/2013    JBLOGGS
2          4           8/1/2013    JBLOGGS
```

The code I am using at the moment is

```
SELECT 
  t1.inquiry_id, 
  t1.state, 
  t1.status, 
  t1.business_impact, 
  t1.priority, 
  t1.owner_rep, 
  t1.owner_grp, 
  t2.change_dt as diary_updated, 
  t2.change_uid as diary_updated_by  
FROM sv_inquiry t1
JOIN sv_diary t2 
  on t1.inquiry_id = t2.inquiry_id
WHERE 
  owner_grp = 'DEV' 
  AND state <> 'Closed' 
  AND status is not null
```

But this brings back all diary entries for each inquiry when I only want the most recent one based on the date in the sv_diary table. How do i do this?

Apologies for the rubbish formattng of the tables but I cant work out how to create a decent table structure on this site.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by latest diary update? All updates that was done today? And what database are you using mysql/Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.inquiry_id, t1.state, t1.status, t1.business_impact, t1.priority, t1.owner_rep, t1.owner_grp, 
 t2.change_dt as diary_updated, t2.change_uid as diary_updated_by  
FROM sv_inquiry t1
JOIN sv_diary t2 on t1.inquiry_id = t2.inquiry_id
WHERE owner_grp = 'DEV' 
AND state <> 'Closed' 
AND status is not null
AND HAVING (t2.change_dt = (Select MAX(t2.change_dt) as Expr1
                                        FROM sv_diary t2 AS data_feed_file_1
                                        where t2.change_dt is not null))
```

Comment: use a having statement to get recent date!

Answer (score 0):

Try group by like :

```
SELECT tt.*,
        t2.change_dt,
        t2.change_uid   
FROM
(
    SELECT  t1.inquiry_id, 
            t1.state, 
            t1.status, 
            t1.business_impact, 
            t1.priority, 
            t1.owner_rep, 
            t1.owner_grp, 
            MAX(t2.diary_id) as diary_id
    FROM sv_inquiry t1
    JOIN sv_diary t2 on t1.inquiry_id = t2.inquiry_id
    WHERE owner_grp = 'DEV' 
    AND state <> 'Closed' 
    AND status is not null
    GROUP BY t1.inquiry_id, t1.state, t1.status, t1.business_impact, t1.priority, t1.owner_rep, t1.owner_grp, 
) tt
INNER JOIN sv_diary td on t1.inquiry_id = t2.inquiry_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below query:-

```
SELECT t1.inquiry_id, t1.state, t1.status, t1.business_impact, t1.priority, t1.owner_rep, t1.owner_grp, 
 t2.change_dt as diary_updated, t2.change_uid as diary_updated_by  
FROM sv_inquiry t1
JOIN (select * from (select d.*,row_number(over partition by inquiry_id order by dairy_updated desc) rn from sv_diary d) where rn =1) t2 on t1.inquiry_id = t2.inquiry_id
WHERE owner_grp = 'DEV' 
AND state <> 'Closed' 
AND status is not null
```

I haven't tested the same , so let me know in case you find any issues.
I have used Analytical query here, which works faster than subquery

Answer (score 0):

You have to order by the date column and restrict it to the first element:

### MYSQL:

```
SELECT 
  t1.inquiry_id, 
  t1.state, 
  t1.status, 
  t1.business_impact, 
  t1.priority, 
  t1.owner_rep, 
  t1.owner_grp, 
  t2.change_dt as diary_updated, 
  t2.change_uid as diary_updated_by  
FROM sv_inquiry t1
JOIN sv_diary t2 
  on t1.inquiry_id = t2.inquiry_id
WHERE 
  owner_grp = 'DEV' 
  AND state <> 'Closed' 
  AND status is not null
ORDER BY t2.change_dt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

### SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1
  t1.inquiry_id, 
  t1.state, 
  t1.status, 
  t1.business_impact, 
  t1.priority, 
  t1.owner_rep, 
  t1.owner_grp, 
  t2.change_dt as diary_updated, 
  t2.change_uid as diary_updated_by  
FROM sv_inquiry t1
JOIN sv_diary t2 
  on t1.inquiry_id = t2.inquiry_id
WHERE 
  owner_grp = 'DEV' 
  AND state <> 'Closed' 
  AND status is not null
ORDER BY t2.change_dt DESC;
```

If you are using a different dbms you can do similar work to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.inquiry_id, t1.state, t1.status, t1.business_impact, t1.priority,
    t1.owner_rep, t1.owner_grp, t2.change_dt as diary_updated,
    t2.change_uid as diary_updated_by
FROM sv_inquiry t1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT t1.*
        FROM sv_diary t1 JOIN(
            SELECT inquery_id, MAX(change_dt)
            FROM sv_diary
            GROUP BY inquery_id
        ) t2 ON t1.inquery_id = t2.inquery_id AND t1.change_dt = t2.change_dt 
    ) t2 on t1.inquiry_id = t2.inquiry_id
WHERE t1.owner_grp = 'DEV' 
    AND t1.state <> 'Closed' 
    AND t1.status is not null
```